Issue Passing NULL StartDate from Main Report to Subreport in SSRS Body:
I'm working on an SSRS report in Visual Studio that passes parameters between a main report and multiple subreports. The goal is to have parameter values Option1 and Option2 that input StartDate param and enter it based on calculations (those options work fine, they're implemented in the stored proc that runs on the subreports) but also to have to option for Manual Entry of StartDate via the calendar (Date/Time value)
I’m running into an issue where passing a NULL value for StartDate from the main report to the subreports causes the reports to fail with error "One or more parameters required to run the report have not been specified" , despite both the main and subreports having StartDate set as nullable. When subreports get hardcoded data, they run just fine. Meaning that I somewhat localized the issue and it's coming from the point the main report gathers the params' values.
My goal is to be able to pass null value in StartDate param from the main report to the subreport. Everything else (like subreport working with the null value in the stored proc) is as good as it gets.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Allowed NULL values in the StartDate parameter: Both in the main and subreports, I marked the StartDate parameter as nullable, but the issue persists.
Added conditional expressions: I included expressions for the StartDate param in the main report to check if StartDate is NULL, and if so, pass EndDate or a hardcoded value instead. This didn’t resolve the issue.
Introduced a hidden parameter (EffectiveStartDate): I created a hidden EffectiveStartDate parameter to pass a value when StartDate is NULL. I used this parameter in place of StartDate in the subreports. The subreports still work fine when run standalone, but the issue persists when running them from the main report.
Feel like I have exhausted all available choices and would be thankful for your advice.
Cheers

I'm not currently in a positions to create reports to test but assuming it's some issue in the SSRS design then I would be tempted to set a default value of some fixed date (e.g. 1900-01-01 00:00:00) and then handle that in your dataset query or stored proc and treat this as if it was a null value passed in.

Was thinking about something similar and already suggested it but the stakeholders insist on "no date to be shown" when using the above mentioned Option1 and Option2.
Otherwise, it's a nice workaround.
What really struck me is that ssrs doesn't allow such NULL values to be passed from main to subreport, but allows subreport to pass them to the stored proc being used. Funny.

If I get a chance, I'll take a look and see if I can replicate but what you might be able to do is set an expression as the parameter passed to the subreport, where you pass a dummy date if the actual parameter is null in the main report. The subreport parameter wont be seen anyway so it should meet your SH's criteria.

Appreciate your time and effort to help.
I already tried different expressions in the subreport param, they don't work because the way I see it -the Nullable StartDate can not sort of "get out of the main report" and be sent to the subreport. Don't know if it makes sense to you explained this way, but what I'm trying to say is that I simply can not mark the main report as null, the generation of the report breaks from the collection of values in the main and doesn't even reach the subreports to try and set up expression there.

update : Went with a Default Value after persuading the biz guys that's the only suitable way. Thanks for the help Alan!

Glad you got it sorted. If I get time, I'll have a look into it, as it's annoying me ! :)

FYI: I setup a report and sub report, passing null dates with no issues. I created the subreport first which takes a start and end date and just dumps out all dates from a calendar table. The start date is null by default and in the query it just chooses 2024-01-01 if start date is null. I then created master report (copied the sub report, removed the table, and replaced that with the subreport). Tested and parameters passed with no problems no matter what dates I chose or if I left it null. If you want I can post as an answer and make the RDL available. Let me know.

Feel free to upload it as answer if you want to, the issues might be coming from the underlying logic in the report (which I have not build myself). Anyway, thanks for your guidance and patience to explore different solutions
